# Order documents in firestore based on their drag and drop position

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My goal is to render my `LinkContainer` components in order that they are in my drag and drop context:

```js
<DragDropContext onDragEnd={handleOnDragEnd}>
          <Droppable droppableId="characters">
            {(provided) => (
              <ul
                className="characters"
                {...provided.droppableProps}
                ref={provided.innerRef}
              >
                {links.map((l, index) => {
                  return (
                    <Draggable key={l.id} draggableId={l.id} index={index}>
                      {(provided) => (
                        <li
                          className="draggable"
                          {...provided.draggableProps}
                          {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                          ref={provided.innerRef}
                        >
                          <LinkContainer
                            linkTitle={l.linkTitle}
                          />
                        </li>
                      )}
                    </Draggable>
                  );
                })}
              </ul>
            )}
          </Droppable>
        </DragDropContext>
```

Here is the function that allows me to drag and drop while also setting `links` to the new order:

```js
 const reorder = (links, startIndex, endIndex) => {
    const result = Array.from(links);
    const [removed] = result.splice(startIndex, 1);
    result.splice(endIndex, 0, removed);

    return result;
  };

  // handle drag end
  const handleOnDragEnd = (result) => {
    console.log(result);
    setLinks(reorder(links, result.source.index, result.destination.index));
  };
```

How can I update my firebase records so that the `LinkContainer`'s render in the last order when mapping through `links` on a page reload?

Do I have to create an index on the document itself and update that with the position of the `LinkContainer`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your proposal to add a property to use it as index, I want to share the following observations:

For example, with this approach you need to update all elements on your list in order to recreate the new order on the database, this will be performed every time that an object is moved.

If this is a small collection this would work, but if your collection has a lot of objects or if you move your objects a lot this will be translated into a lot of read and write operations.

*in the worst scenario*

```
(documents in collection) * (# of movements)
```

Another alternative is to create an array(arrays always are static on his order) with desired order, for example this is the default state of the objects within collection

```
["1a","1c","2b","3x"]
```

But after the movements on the frontend this looks like this

```
["1a","2b","3x","1c"]
```

The state of the frontend can be stored in an array within a document in a separate collection, in order to not modify the original objects and avoid to re-update all elements in each movement, but this will continue to be affected for the quantity of movements that the users perform in the frontend and also you need to be updated the array based on creation or deletion of documents on the collection.

You will have to follow the array order to display your information in the desired way.

The last alternative and maybe the less effective is rewriting the complete collection(with a Frontend snapshot) every time a movement happen, rewrite a collection counts as a single write operation, but this can generate future problems with concurrent operations.

Comment: This is great! Thank you!