# What's the best way to assign a priority to document (order) - Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have a collection of orders and by **default** I want to create a field called `priority` that, at the time of creation, is the size of the collection. That's the only way I can think of to get a auto-incrementing number in Firestore.

My only issue is that the orders get added via a batch write. So even if I fire off an `onCreate` cloud function, the possibility of querying the collection size and getting back the same value is, I think, high.

My reason for wanting the priority this way is because changing the priority is a dragging and dropping rows on a table on the front-end. I just swap the priorities and write the new priorities to Firestore. That way when the table is loaded up again, I can `sortBy` priority and deliver a sensible experience.

How can I get a unique, auto-incrementing number for this use case?

I know this is subjective, but I've spent way too much time thinking about this as it is.

Comment: I am not sure the question is clear. If you are doing a 'batch write' which I assume means you are doing it in a transaction, you would also include the count in that write as well so it would all line up. It's not clear how that will create a 'priority' and what that has to do with dragging a dropping in a table. If you want to persist the sort order, you would either do that directly in each document, or and preferably, keep that order in a separate document that references each document you want to keep sorted.

Comment: @Jay no a batch write is different from a transaction only because the operation only contains writes. A transaction can contain reads and writes. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions

If you take the size of the collection as a priority then the first doc added would have a P of 1 and the second doc added a P of 2. Then if I wanted wanted to swap the priority, it's a matter of changing P in Doc 1 to 2 and P in Doc 2 to 1.

Comment: This now means when I load the table and sortBy priority, Doc 2 would show up first then Doc 1. I'm using the size of the collection as a way to get a auto-incrementing number

Comment: I am familiar with transactions - the point of my comment was you are performing Firebase tasks within a transaction so it either all passes or fails. It's not clear how having  a count of the documents in a collection would lead to the first document having priority of 1 or what an auto-incrementing number has to with a documents priority. We really need to see the code you're having difficulty with, a screenshot of your Firestore database and a more clear explanation of the issue. Also, when responding to another user, precede their name with and at symbol. Like @Jay.

Comment: Hi @Jay I found a question that seems to better explain what I'm trying to do. I apologise for not being clear in my original explanation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65170678/order-documents-in-firestore-based-on-their-drag-and-drop-position I've gone ahead and closed the question

Comment: To clarify, you have a list of items displayed to the user which can be drag and dropped to change the order and you wish to keep track of the ordering of those objects. If that's correct, you need to look into a linked list or storing a separate ordering collection. In other words, when a change is made to the ordering, write the new order to a separate collection for that user. That also enabled each use to have their own ordering. If that's not what you're doing - maybe the answer to the linked question helps.

Comment: @Jay that's exactly what I'm doing. I eventually discovered, as your suggestion notes as well, that I'd have to store a separate ordering collection as well. When I've implemented it I'll post a solution here. Thanks for the direction!