# How to structure drag and drop data in firebase firestore?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, drag-and-drop, react-beautiful-dnd

I want to add realtime drag and drop support for my react-firebase app. Right now the structure is like, I have 'sessions' collection and under it, there is 'ideas' collection which has multiple fields and I am trying to add drag and drop support for 'ideas'.

Column names are not important in my case, for sure I will have 5 columns all the time, and currently my drag and drop support works well without updating firestore. At this point I am not sure about how to structure the data. Locally my data is structured something like this:

```js
[[{single idea}, {single idea}], [{single idea}], [], [], [], []]
```

You can think arrays as columns and its elements are ordered inside that columns. I tried to add column, and order field inside of idea but I don't think it is possible update it correctly.

Maybe I can achive a data structure like this:

```
[{col1: [{}, {},]}, {col2: [{}]}]
```

Which is like you have an Array under it there is a map with column name as key value and under that there is another array which has idea maps. Again, I am not sure how to implement such a structure here is my reorder and move functions:

Reorder: for ordering elements inside of a column

```js
    const reorder = (list, startIndex, endIndex) => {
    const result = Array.from(list);
    const [removed] = result.splice(startIndex, 1);
    result.splice(endIndex, 0, removed);
        console.log(result);
    return result;
    };
```

Move: moving elements to other columns

```js
    const move = (source, destination, droppableSource, droppableDestination) => {
    const sourceClone = Array.from(source);
    const destClone = Array.from(destination);
    const [removed] = sourceClone.splice(droppableSource.index, 1);

    destClone.splice(droppableDestination.index, 0, removed);

    const result = {};
    result[droppableSource.droppableId] = sourceClone;
    result[droppableDestination.droppableId] = destClone;

    return result;
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65185638/15747954) where there's various alternatives to your question.

One of the suggestions is to create an array with desired order, ex. initial order: `[1,2,3,4,5]` and after user movements: `[2,1,4,3,5]`, and store it in an array within a document in a separate collection in order to avoid to re-update all elements in each movement.

Comment: In addition I suggest you have a look at this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r5ZEqaW3A5c) where is shown how to implement it with AngularFire.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I have solved by using css order in a flexbox container. And I am just keeping order number in firestore. Anyway columns are not important for me as I stated. Everytime I move a card I update the order value. With this I can keep my container responsive.

Comment: Nice to hear it has been solved! I recommend you post an answer with the solution in case some other user face the same problem.

Comment: Sure, I'll do it.